# Scrollbar doesn't appear in parent control if the child is docked to the edge

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I wonder why the child control cannot be scrolled even though it cannot fit its container.
Here is my simple example of the layout:

[image]

I have orange panel and green panel inside. Orange panel has AutoScroll set to true.
Green panel is docked to top and has minimum width = 150.
Why the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear on orange panel?

Without DockStyle=Top everything works fine. I could use Anchors, but I feel more comfortable with docking when creating more complex layouts with many groupboxes and panels stacked on each other.
I also don't like using AutoScrollMinSize because it sets the limit regardless of what controls are currently visible on the form.

The question is why does it work this way?

P.S. Just let me know if this is by design and there is no other way except Anchors on green panel or AutoScrollMinSize on orange panel. It seems weird to me that it cannot display the scrollbar in that case even though you have child control that cannot fit into its parent and parent has AutoScroll=true. I guess the layout engine doesn't even bother calculating the actual width of the docked control because in theory it is stretched to whatever parent width you have.

Comment: the green one is inside the orange one?

Comment: yes, the green panel is inside of the orange panel.

Comment: and nothing else on the form?

Comment: nothing else. This is a test project where I reproduced this behavior, there are only two panels.

Comment: Looks like it is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is by design. I checked the code of the ScrollableControl from which Panel and therefore other containers like TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel are inherited.
The horizontal scrollbar will not be checked if the child control has:

```
Dock=Top|Bottom|Fill|Right or Anchor=Right or Anchor!=Left
```

And the same picture is for vertical scrollbar, it is ignored when the child control has:

```
Dock=Left|Bottom|Fill|Right or Anchor=Bottom or Anchor!=Top
```

There is nothing much I can do except using AutoScrollMinSize or right combination of anchors.